# Memory leak when using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have memory leak problem when running the following code. I removed unnecessary parts of code as much as I can. When I running this, the usage of memory for cpu and swap is getting bigger and it reaches the maximum of it and ended up killing the program with the exit code 9. I changed the process save its result with saving csv file and release all variables with del command. But, I do not know the further solution.  Thanks in advance!!

```
@njit
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km


def get_similiar_candidates_lambda(i, r, df_emd, dists):
    KM_MAX_DISTANCE = 1.0
    TOP_K = 5
    similiar_min_candidates, similiar_max_candidates = [], []
    viz_candidates = []
    dists = {k: v for k, v in dists.items() if v <= KM_MAX_DISTANCE}

    for c in df_emd.itertuples():
        if i != c.Index:
            dc = c._asdict()
            if r['용도지역1'] == dc['용도지역1'] and r['지목'] == dc['지목']:
                try:
                    euclidean_distance = dists[(r.name, dc['Index'])]
                    if  euclidean_distance <= KM_MAX_DISTANCE:
                            if dc['도로접면'] in pair_road_cond[r['도로접면']] and dc['토지이용상황'] in pair_land_usage[r['토지이용상황']]:
                                if r['종류'] != '토지' and r['건물가격_추정'] != 0.:   # 총액, 단가 기준 추가
                                    total_price_prop = (dc['건물가격_추정'] + dc['공시가격_2022'] * dc['Mutiple_Pred'] ) / ( r['건물가격_추정'] + r['공시가격_2022'] * r['Mutiple_Pred'] )
                                else:
                                    total_price_prop = None

                                unit_price_prop = (dc['공시가격_2022'] * dc['Mutiple_Pred']) /  (r['공시가격_2022'] * r['Mutiple_Pred'])

                                lb_total_price_prop, ub_total_price_prop = 0.5, 1.5
                                lb_unit_price_prop, ub_unit_price_prop = 0.5, 1.5

                                check1 = total_price_prop is not None and (lb_total_price_prop <= total_price_prop and total_price_prop <= ub_total_price_prop)
                                check2 = lb_unit_price_prop <= unit_price_prop and unit_price_prop <= ub_unit_price_prop
                                if check1: 
                                    similiar_min_candidates.append((c.Index, euclidean_distance))
                                if check1 and check2:
                                    similiar_max_candidates.append((c.Index, euclidean_distance))
                except KeyError as e: 
                    continue
                viz_candidates.append((c.Index, euclidean_distance))  # 반경 1km 내의 용도지역1과 지목이 같은 케이스

    generals = [t for t in viz_candidates]
    min_candidates, max_candidates = None, None

    if len(similiar_min_candidates) > TOP_K:
        similiar_min_candidates.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])   
        min_candidates = [t for t in similiar_min_candidates][:5]
    elif len(similiar_min_candidates) >=1 and len(similiar_min_candidates) <= 5:
        min_candidates = [t for t in similiar_min_candidates]
    if len(similiar_min_candidates) > TOP_K:
        similiar_min_candidates.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])   
        max_candidates = [t for t in similiar_max_candidates][:5]
    elif len(similiar_min_candidates) >=1 and len(similiar_max_candidates) <= 5:
        max_candidates = [t for t in similiar_max_candidates]

    return min_candidates, max_candidates, generals


def process_emd(args, tuple_emd):
    sd, sgg, emd = tuple_emd
    
    df_land_ai = get_land_ai(src_url, sql_land_ai)
    df_land    = get_land(dm_url, sql_land)
    df_final = pd.merge(df_land_ai, df_land, on='pnu', how='right')

    df_final['Mutiple_Pred'] = df_final['predicted_land_price'] / df_final['공시가격_2022']
    df_final = df_final.loc[:, columns]
    df_final = df_final.set_index('pnu')
    df_final = df_final[~df_final['Mutiple_Pred'].isna()] 
    df_emd = df_final[~df_final.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
    
    candidate = list(df_emd.index)
    geo = df_emd[['lon_x', 'lat_y']].to_numpy()
    geos = np.asarray(list(it.product(geo, geo))).reshape(-1, 4)
    euclideans = haversine_np(geos[:,0], geos[:,1], geos[:,2], geos[:,3])  

    KM_MAX_DISTANCE = 1.0
    TOP_K = 5
    
    df_emd.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_emd_cp = pd.merge(df_emd, df_emd, how='cross', suffixes=('_x', '_y')) # cartesian product for df_emd for speed up
    df_emd_cp['euclidean_distance'] = euclideans
    df_emd_cp = df_emd_cp[df_emd_cp['euclidean_distance'] < KM_MAX_DISTANCE] # remove euclidean distance > 1km in advance for speed up
    df_emd_cp = df_emd_cp[df_emd_cp['pnu_x'] != df_emd_cp['pnu_y']] 
    df_emd_cp = df_emd_cp[df_emd_cp.apply(lambda x: True if x['도로접면_y'] in pair_road_cond[x['도로접면_x']] else False, axis=1)] # 236
    df_emd_cp = df_emd_cp[df_emd_cp.apply(lambda x: True if x['토지이용상황_y'] in x['토지이용상황_x'] in pair_land_usage.keys() and pair_land_usage[x['토지이용상황_x']] else False, axis=1)] # 193
    df_emd_cp['unit_price_prop'] = (df_emd_cp['공시가격_2022_y'] * df_emd_cp['Mutiple_Pred_y']) / (df_emd_cp['공시가격_2022_x'] * df_emd_cp['Mutiple_Pred_x'])

    lb_total_price_prop, ub_total_price_prop = 0.5, 1.5
    lb_unit_price_prop, ub_unit_price_prop = 0.5, 1.5

    df_emd_cp['check1'] = df_emd_cp['total_price_prop'].apply(lambda x : np.isnan(x) or (x is not None and (lb_total_price_prop <= x and x <= ub_total_price_prop)))
    df_emd_cp['check2'] = df_emd_cp['unit_price_prop'].apply(lambda x : x is not None and  (lb_unit_price_prop <= x and x <= ub_unit_price_prop))

    if len(df_emd_cp) > 1:
        df_similiar_min_candidates =  df_emd_cp.groupby(by=['pnu_x'], group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: 
                                                                            (sorted(
                                                                                zip(x.loc[x['check1'], 'pnu_y'].tolist(), 
                                                                                    x.loc[x['check1'], 'euclidean_distance'].tolist()),
                                                                                    key=lambda x:x[1])[:min(TOP_K, x['check1'].sum())])
                                                                            ).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'similiar_min_candidates'})
        
        df_similiar_max_candidates =  df_emd_cp.groupby(by=['pnu_x'], group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: 
                                                                            sorted(
                                                                                zip(x.loc[(x['check1'] & x['check2']), 'pnu_y'].tolist(), 
                                                                                    x.loc[(x['check1'] & x['check2']), 'euclidean_distance'].tolist()),
                                                                                    key=lambda x:x[1])[: min( TOP_K, (x['check1'] & x['check2']).sum())]
                                                                            ).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'similiar_max_candidates'})

        if len(df_similiar_min_candidates) != 0:
            df_similiar_min_candidates = df_similiar_min_candidates[['pnu_x', 'similiar_min_candidates']] 
            df_similiar_min_candidates.rename(columns={'pnu_x':'pnu'}, inplace=True, errors='ignore') # euclidean_distance
            df_similiar_min_candidates = df_similiar_min_candidates[df_similiar_min_candidates['similiar_min_candidates'].apply(lambda x: x is not None and len(x) > 0)]
            df_emd_final = df_similiar_min_candidates.merge(df_emd, how='left', on='pnu')
            df_neighbors = df_emd_final[['pnu']].copy()
            df_land_neighbors = df_neighbors.merge(df_emd_final, how='left', on='pnu')
            df_land_neighbors = df_land_neighbors.groupby(by=['pnu'], group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame.from_records(x['similiar_min_candidates'].iloc[0], columns=['neighbor_pnu', 'neighbor_distance'])).reset_index()
            df_land_neighbors = df_land_neighbors.rename(columns={'level_1':'neighbor_seq'})

            df_land_neighbors = df_land_neighbors.loc[:, ['criteria_id', 'criteria_version', 'pnu', 'neighbor_seq', 'neighbor_pnu', 'neighbor_distance', 'sd', 'sgg', 'emd', 'createdat', 'updatedat']]
            df_building = pd.read_sql(sql_building, con=get_db_connection('dm'))
            
            df_neighbors = df_land_neighbors[['pnu', 'neighbor_pnu', 'neighbor_seq', 'neighbor_distance', 'sd', 'sgg', 'emd']]
            df_neighbors = df_neighbors.rename(columns={'pnu': 'base_pnu'})

            df_right = pd.merge(df_neighbors, df_building.loc[:, df_building.columns.isin(['pnu','building_master_id'])], left_on='neighbor_pnu', right_on='pnu')
            df_right.rename(columns={'building_master_id': 'neighbor_building_master_id'}, inplace=True)
            result = pd.merge(df_building.loc[:, df_building.columns.isin(['pnu','building_master_id'])], df_right, left_on='pnu', right_on='base_pnu')

            df_ai_building_neighbors = result[['criteria_id', 'criteria_version', 'building_master_id', 'neighbor_building_master_id', 'neighbor_distance', 'sd', 'sgg', 'emd']]

            os.makedirs(f'data/{sd}/{sgg}/{emd}', exist_ok=True)
            df_ai_building_neighbors.to_csv(f'data/{sd}/{sgg}/{emd}/ai_building_neighbors.csv', index=False)
            df_land_neighbors.to_csv(f'data/{sd}/{sgg}/{emd}/ai_land_neighbors.csv', index=False)
            del result, df_ai_building_neighbors, df_neighbors, df_right, df_building, df_similiar_min_candidates, df_similiar_max_candidates, df_emd_final, df_land_neighbors
        del df_emd_cp, df_land_ai, df_land, df_final, df_emd, geo, geos, euclideans
    else:
        del df_emd_cp, df_land_ai, df_land, df_final, df_emd, geo, geos, euclideans

    t.toc(msg=f'Elapsed time for getting similiar properties of {emd} : ', restart=True)


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='lightgbm to evaluate land price')
    parser.add_argument('--model_id', type=str, default='lightgbm', help='model id')
    parser.add_argument('--model_version', type=str, default='3.0', help='model version')
    parser.add_argument('--data_version', type=str, default='230525')
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()
    NUM_CORES = 5
    df_emd = pd.read_sql(sql_emd, con=get_db_connection('src'))

    pool = Pool(NUM_CORES)
    pool.starmap(process_emd, itertools.product([args], list(zip(df_emd.sd2, df_emd.sgg, df_emd.emd))))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Why do you think you are leaking memory? Neither Python nor Pandas are known to have memory leaks. But processing large sets of data with Pandas is known to be very memory consuming, and when using multiprocessing, each process has its own copy of the process memory. You may just have exhausted the available resources, including the swap...

Comment: Highly unlikely that you're leaking memory. More probable is that each subprocess is using a large amount of memory and you have too many concurrent processes for the resources available on your machine. Maybe try NUM_CORES = 2. Runtime will be slower than you'd hope but fewer resources will be required. Use a platform-specific monitor to see how much memory is being used by Python

Comment: Yes, I think I decreased the number of cores. Maybe it causes due to size of dataframe is big.  I need to adhere this inevitably.